# Postgres for Rails and Heroku: 'which psql' still /usr/local/bin/psql even after adding export PATH=... to ~/.bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

From the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup):

> The OS X version of psql should point to the path containing the
>   Postgres.app directory. For example if you are using version 9.5, the
>   output will look similar to this:

```
$ which psql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/psql
```

I guess the first question is what is going on here? Why would this be somewhere else? But it is. After I do the suggested fix from the [Postgress docs](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html):

> If you are using bash (default shell on OS X), add the following line
>   to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

I still get:

```
$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

Everything else seems to be working as expected, but I can't get this straight! The other info I can think to include here is that I installed with Homebrew before downloading the app version 9.5.3.

EDIT: A little more info discovered. Inside /usr/local/bin/, all the files are aliases! Unfortunately, they go to /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/bin, which is still wrong according to the Heroku docs sited above. Why does it need to be that why anyway? And how can I update?

EDIT EDIT: A bit more info. Here is my path variable:

$ $PATH
-bash: /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/Users/ME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:“:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin”:/Users/ME/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory

So it does look like a precedence issue, which is actually an underlying issue between Homebrew and the App. Brings up two more question, why did this happen? Does this even matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the executable out of the bin for the time-being, until you figure a more permanent fix. `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/psql ~/psql.backup` and try `which psql` again. It may be that `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence over the custom path you have set.